# Sending a UDP with scapy shows malformed in wireshark

Tags: python, scapy

If i try and send a UDP packet with python using scapy

```
from scapy.all import *
    data= "hello"
    a = IP(dst="192.168.192.145")/UDP(dport=1194)/Raw(load=data)
    send(a)
    a.show()
```

It shows as both malformed and as the DNS protocol in wireshark

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out by setting my source port to 50000

Comment: This did not work for me.